# VBA Excel Toggle Button "Latching"

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have the following code corresponding to three ToggleButtons in a VBA Program in Excel. When one button is clicked, it is supposed to stay "pressed" and the other two buttons are supposed to "release". However, with the code I have, I have to click on one button TWICE, once to release the other buttons and the other to keep the original one pressed.

However, if I add "ToggleButtonX.Value = True" to each of the Subs, when one button is clicked, it cannot release even after clicking another button. How could one configure this so that when one clicks on one button, that button stays pressed AND the other buttons get released?

EDIT: I would like to KEEP TOGGLEBUTTONS.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    ToggleButton2.Value = False
    ToggleButton3.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    ToggleButton1.Value = False
    ToggleButton3.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()
    ToggleButton1.Value = False
    ToggleButton2.Value = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use option buttons instead of toggle buttons?  They're functionality for this purpose is fully reliable

Comment: The reason it's unreliable is that each time you change the value of the ToggleButton VBA sees it as a click and it fires the `Click` event and thus each piece of code everytime.

Comment: So, how would I fix this? I would like to keep it as ToggleButtons

Comment: Oliver most likely has the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `ToggleButtonx.Value = False` you are simulating a click on that button and so it own code will run, and set the value of the button you just clicked to false.

Use instead the `MouseDown` event:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ToggleButton2.Value = False
    ToggleButton3.Value = False
End Sub
Private Sub ToggleButton2_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ToggleButton1.Value = False
    ToggleButton3.Value = False
End Sub
Private Sub ToggleButton3_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ToggleButton1.Value = False
    ToggleButton2.Value = False
End Sub
```

Comment: this will set the other buttons to false (not clicked) regardless of whether the original button is true or false (clicked or not).

Comment: This worked better for me as I could change buttons multiple times, whereas the solution below only allowed one change and then locked up

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the [OptionButton answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38570073/2662901), which is probably easier and cleaner to implement, there's another way to do it as well by using logic that will only change the values of the other two buttons when one button is clicked. The code for the other buttons `Click` event will fire, but the variable `sButton` will determine that the code will only fire on the button that was *physically* pressed by the user.

Also note the use of `Not Me.ToggleButton1.Value`. This will ensure that button 2 and 3 are the opposite of button 1 *with each click*. The way your code was written, it would always revert the other buttons to `False` no matter what if the clicked button was `True` or `False`.

```
Option Explicit

Public sButton As String

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

ButtonLoad 1

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()

ButtonLoad 2

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()

ButtonLoad 3

End Sub

Sub ButtonLoad(iButton As Integer)

Select Case iButton
    Case 1
        If sButton = "" Then
            sButton = "1" 'set so that other buttons don't trigger
            Me.ToggleButton2.Value = Not Me.ToggleButton1.Value
            Me.ToggleButton3.Value = Not Me.ToggleButton1.Value
            sButton = "" 'reset for next button click
        End If
    Case 2
        If sButton = "" Then
            sButton = "2"
            Me.ToggleButton1.Value = Not Me.ToggleButton2.Value
            Me.ToggleButton3.Value = Not Me.ToggleButton2.Value
            sButton = ""
        End If
    Case 3
        If sButton = "" Then
            sButton = "3"
            Me.ToggleButton2.Value = Not Me.ToggleButton3.Value
            Me.ToggleButton1.Value = Not Me.ToggleButton3.Value
            sButton = ""
        End If
End Select
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with Option Buttons (If that works with the rest of your implementation)

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    OptionButton1.Value = True
    OptionButton2.Value = False
    OptionButton3.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    OptionButton1.Value = False
    OptionButton2.Value = True
    OptionButton3.Value = False
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    OptionButton1.Value = False
    OptionButton2.Value = False
    OptionButton3.Value = True
End Sub
```